# Error propagation for ratio data

Tags: error-propagation, ratio

I'm working with some published ratio data for isotopes of uranium (238U) and lead (208Pb and 206Pb).  The data are published in ratios of 238U/208Pb and 206Pb/208Pb, but I need the data to be in the form 238U/206Pb, which is simple enough to do.  238U = a, 208Pb = b and 206Pb = c:

(a/b) / (c/b) = a/c

Therefore:

(238U/208Pb) / (206Pb/208Pb) = 238U/206Pb

Each of the original isotope ratios has an associated error value, which is given as an absolute value at the 1 sigma level.  Using the available data e.g. ratio and error values, would it be possible to calculate the associated error for the 238U/206Pb ratio, and if so, how would one go about doing this?

Here's an example of some data, I've also included a ρ (correlation coefficient for the original ratio data in case it's of any use.

206Pb/208Pb 1σ abs  238U/208Pb  1σ abs  ρ
1.235           0.054   1652            119 0.9912

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Consider your expression as $f(u, v)= u/v$, expand by Taylor's theorem:
$$
f(u_0 + a, v_0 + b) = f( u_0, v_0) + f_u( u_0, v_0) a+ f_v( u_0, v_0) b + \ldots
$$
Here $f_u( u_0, v_0)$ is the partial derivative with respect to $u$. Under the assumption that the above *linear* relation is correct, and that the errors are independent, it will give you the standard deviation of the error from the standard deviations of the errors in $u$ and $v$. You can continue the expansion to include cross terms to account for correlations, but that gets messy real fast.